# How do i increase the size of plane in SVG which is a path

Tags: html, svg

I have just started learning SVG and I am from management background.

To me path is creating a trouble in understanding SVG. I could create circle, rectangle and translate and scale for now but I could not play with path.

I have created a JSfiddle to play with SVG and creative animation: http://jsbin.com/hificutebu/3/edit?html,output

You can see, I have animated plane to move from downward to upward but the plane looks so tiny.

How do i increase its size so it looks perfect? Plane is being created using path. Can anyone please help me to increase the size with explanation?

```
<g id="plane" transform="translate(45, 8)" fill="#C3922E">
<path d="M23.9521429,16.0247273 C24.0607143,15.4996364 22.1314286,9.57454545 22.1728571,9.41454545 C22.4507143,9.21454545 23.6271429,8.10618182 23.6271429,7.93745455 C23.6271429,7.76872727 22.8571429,6.99054545 22.72,7.01090909 C22.5835714,7.032 21.9328571,7.73818182 21.7728571,7.95127273 C21.63,7.95490909 21.26,5.92654545 21.4085714,5.77527273 C21.5578571,5.62327273 23.1907143,4.09963636 24.2078571,3.04290909 C25.0607143,2.15636364 25.2457143,0.761454545 25.1285714,0.641454545 C25.0107143,0.522181818 23.6407143,0.710545455 22.77,1.57890909 C21.7321429,2.61454545 20.2357143,4.27636364 20.0864286,4.42909091 C19.9378571,4.57963636 17.9464286,4.20290909 17.9492857,4.05745455 C18.1592857,3.89381818 18.8528571,3.23272727 18.8721429,3.09309091 C18.8928571,2.95490909 18.1285714,2.16872727 17.9628571,2.16872727 C17.7964286,2.16872727 16.7092857,3.36654545 16.5114286,3.64945455 C16.3542857,3.69236364 10.535,1.728 10.02,1.83927273 C9.505,1.94909091 8.88857143,2.42836364 9.02785714,2.57018182 C9.16714286,2.71127273 13.6592857,4.76872727 14.44,5.27054545 C15.22,5.77309091 16.7171429,7.23927273 16.7171429,7.41672727 C16.7171429,7.59490909 12.7042857,12.1796364 12.4707143,12.3730909 C12.2371429,12.5658182 10.5071429,11.7127273 9.83571429,11.808 C9.16357143,11.9025455 8.64428571,12.408 8.68642857,12.5665455 C8.72857143,12.7243636 11.3271429,13.9047273 11.1978571,14.1330909 C11.0971429,14.3098182 10.3671429,15.5018182 10.4507143,15.5869091 C10.5342857,15.6712727 11.7057143,14.9287273 11.8792857,14.8261818 C12.1042857,14.6930909 13.2635714,17.3410909 13.4178571,17.384 C13.5728571,17.4261818 14.07,16.8967273 14.1621429,16.2130909 C14.2557143,15.5287273 13.4178571,13.768 13.6078571,13.5301818 C13.7971429,13.2923636 18.3,9.20654545 18.4757143,9.20654545 C18.6507143,9.20654545 20.09,10.7301818 20.5828571,11.5250909 C21.0764286,12.3192727 23.0964286,16.8930909 23.2357143,17.0349091 C23.3735714,17.1774545 23.8428571,16.5483636 23.9521429,16.0247273 L23.9521429,20.0247273 Z" id="Shape"></path>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M1.81642857,25.7505455 C2.30571429,24.7767273 2.87714286,23.8269091 3.49642857,22.8974545 C3.81142857,22.4363636 4.13428571,21.9774545 4.47428571,21.5294545 L4.72714286,21.192 L4.98785714,20.8589091 C5.16071429,20.6356364 5.34071429,20.4181818 5.52071429,20.1992727 C5.88142857,19.7636364 6.25214286,19.3352727 6.63071429,18.912 C6.82,18.7010909 7.01214286,18.4989091 7.20214286,18.2909091 L7.80357143,17.6661818 L8.4,17.0705455 C8.60571429,16.8749091 8.80785714,16.6756364 9.015,16.4829091 C9.43071429,16.0989091 9.85,15.7185455 10.2785714,15.3512727 C10.2814286,15.3483636 10.2835714,15.3469091 10.2871429,15.3447273 C10.4628571,15.032 10.65,14.7229091 10.6971429,14.64 C10.7557143,14.5352727 10.2542857,14.2370909 9.685,13.9265455 C9.57214286,14.0181818 9.45928571,14.1112727 9.34642857,14.2036364 C9.11785714,14.3883636 8.89714286,14.5825455 8.67357143,14.7745455 C8.45,14.9665455 8.23571429,15.1687273 8.01642857,15.3658182 C7.79928571,15.5643636 7.58714286,15.7709091 7.37285714,15.9730909 L6.73714286,16.6007273 L6.13642857,17.2305455 C5.93571429,17.4516364 5.73071429,17.6698182 5.53428571,17.8909091 C5.14285714,18.3338182 4.75785714,18.7825455 4.39214286,19.2458182 C4.20857143,19.4763636 4.025,19.7083636 3.84928571,19.944 L3.58285714,20.2974545 L3.32428571,20.6552727 C2.98,21.1323636 2.65857143,21.6247273 2.34285714,22.1192727 C2.19,22.3694545 2.03428571,22.6181818 1.88714286,22.8698182 C1.74285714,23.1272727 1.59571429,23.3789091 1.46071429,23.6378182 C1.18142857,24.1490909 0.927857143,24.6741818 0.69,25.2014545 C0.473571429,25.7054545 0.272142857,26.2123636 0.0971428571,26.7287273 C0.385,27.0487273 0.685714286,27.3570909 0.992857143,27.6581818 C1.045,27.5149091 1.09428571,27.3701818 1.14928571,27.2261818 C1.34571429,26.7287273 1.575,26.2385455 1.81642857,25.7505455 L1.81642857,25.7505455 Z" id="Shape"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M2.61857143,28.7214545 C2.81428571,28.2232727 3.04357143,27.7330909 3.285,27.2458182 C3.77428571,26.272 4.34571429,25.3214545 4.96571429,24.3927273 C5.28,23.9316364 5.60285714,23.4727273 5.94357143,23.024 L6.19714286,22.6865455 L6.45785714,22.3541818 C6.63,22.1301818 6.81,21.912 6.99071429,21.6938182 C7.35142857,21.2581818 7.72214286,20.8298182 8.10071429,20.4065455 C8.28928571,20.1956364 8.48142857,19.9941818 8.67214286,19.7861818 L9.27428571,19.1614545 L9.87,18.5650909 C10.075,18.3694545 10.2778571,18.1709091 10.485,17.9774545 C10.9007143,17.5941818 11.32,17.2130909 11.7478571,16.8458182 C11.8821429,16.7309091 12.0171429,16.6167273 12.1528571,16.5032727 C11.8235714,15.8690909 11.49,15.2690909 11.3792857,15.3330909 C11.3185714,15.3694545 11.135,15.4843636 10.9185714,15.6145455 C10.8842857,15.6429091 10.85,15.6698182 10.815,15.6989091 C10.5857143,15.8829091 10.3657143,16.0778182 10.1414286,16.2698182 C9.91785714,16.4618182 9.70357143,16.664 9.48428571,16.8603636 C9.26642857,17.0596364 9.055,17.2661818 8.84071429,17.4683636 L8.205,18.0967273 L7.60428571,18.7265455 C7.40357143,18.9469091 7.19857143,19.1658182 7.00214286,19.3869091 C6.61071429,19.8298182 6.22571429,20.2785455 5.86,20.7410909 C5.67642857,20.9723636 5.49285714,21.2029091 5.31714286,21.4392727 L5.05142857,21.7927273 L4.79285714,22.1512727 C4.44928571,22.6283636 4.12642857,23.1207273 3.81142857,23.6145455 C3.65928571,23.8654545 3.50357143,24.1127273 3.35642857,24.3658182 C3.21214286,24.6210909 3.06428571,24.872 2.93,25.1309091 C2.65071429,25.6421818 2.39785714,26.1672727 2.16,26.6945455 C1.94642857,27.1927273 1.74642857,27.6938182 1.57357143,28.2029091 C1.87928571,28.48 2.19428571,28.7447273 2.51714286,29.0014545 C2.55071429,28.9090909 2.58214286,28.8145455 2.61857143,28.7214545 L2.61857143,28.7214545 Z" id="Shape"/>
<animateTransform
   attributeName="transform"
   id="plane"
   type="translate"
   from="15 40"
   to="45 8"
   dur="2s"
   begin="0s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<animateTransform>` applies to the entire element that it is contained within (in your example, it is contained within the `<g>` element). It will therefore override the transform of the `<g>` element. Therefore, you have three options to resolve this:

**Option 1**

Use another `<animateTransform>`. This would be more beneficial if you wanted the size to change as in the example below, but you could also keep the `to` and `from` sizes the same.:

```
<g id="plane" fill="#C3922E">
<path d="M23.9521429,16.0247273 C24.0607143,15.4996364 22.1314286,9.57454545 22.1728571,9.41454545 C22.4507143,9.21454545 23.6271429,8.10618182 23.6271429,7.93745455 C23.6271429,7.76872727 22.8571429,6.99054545 22.72,7.01090909 C22.5835714,7.032 21.9328571,7.73818182 21.7728571,7.95127273 C21.63,7.95490909 21.26,5.92654545 21.4085714,5.77527273 C21.5578571,5.62327273 23.1907143,4.09963636 24.2078571,3.04290909 C25.0607143,2.15636364 25.2457143,0.761454545 25.1285714,0.641454545 C25.0107143,0.522181818 23.6407143,0.710545455 22.77,1.57890909 C21.7321429,2.61454545 20.2357143,4.27636364 20.0864286,4.42909091 C19.9378571,4.57963636 17.9464286,4.20290909 17.9492857,4.05745455 C18.1592857,3.89381818 18.8528571,3.23272727 18.8721429,3.09309091 C18.8928571,2.95490909 18.1285714,2.16872727 17.9628571,2.16872727 C17.7964286,2.16872727 16.7092857,3.36654545 16.5114286,3.64945455 C16.3542857,3.69236364 10.535,1.728 10.02,1.83927273 C9.505,1.94909091 8.88857143,2.42836364 9.02785714,2.57018182 C9.16714286,2.71127273 13.6592857,4.76872727 14.44,5.27054545 C15.22,5.77309091 16.7171429,7.23927273 16.7171429,7.41672727 C16.7171429,7.59490909 12.7042857,12.1796364 12.4707143,12.3730909 C12.2371429,12.5658182 10.5071429,11.7127273 9.83571429,11.808 C9.16357143,11.9025455 8.64428571,12.408 8.68642857,12.5665455 C8.72857143,12.7243636 11.3271429,13.9047273 11.1978571,14.1330909 C11.0971429,14.3098182 10.3671429,15.5018182 10.4507143,15.5869091 C10.5342857,15.6712727 11.7057143,14.9287273 11.8792857,14.8261818 C12.1042857,14.6930909 13.2635714,17.3410909 13.4178571,17.384 C13.5728571,17.4261818 14.07,16.8967273 14.1621429,16.2130909 C14.2557143,15.5287273 13.4178571,13.768 13.6078571,13.5301818 C13.7971429,13.2923636 18.3,9.20654545 18.4757143,9.20654545 C18.6507143,9.20654545 20.09,10.7301818 20.5828571,11.5250909 C21.0764286,12.3192727 23.0964286,16.8930909 23.2357143,17.0349091 C23.3735714,17.1774545 23.8428571,16.5483636 23.9521429,16.0247273 L23.9521429,20.0247273 Z" id="Shape"></path>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M1.81642857,25.7505455 C2.30571429,24.7767273 2.87714286,23.8269091 3.49642857,22.8974545 C3.81142857,22.4363636 4.13428571,21.9774545 4.47428571,21.5294545 L4.72714286,21.192 L4.98785714,20.8589091 C5.16071429,20.6356364 5.34071429,20.4181818 5.52071429,20.1992727 C5.88142857,19.7636364 6.25214286,19.3352727 6.63071429,18.912 C6.82,18.7010909 7.01214286,18.4989091 7.20214286,18.2909091 L7.80357143,17.6661818 L8.4,17.0705455 C8.60571429,16.8749091 8.80785714,16.6756364 9.015,16.4829091 C9.43071429,16.0989091 9.85,15.7185455 10.2785714,15.3512727 C10.2814286,15.3483636 10.2835714,15.3469091 10.2871429,15.3447273 C10.4628571,15.032 10.65,14.7229091 10.6971429,14.64 C10.7557143,14.5352727 10.2542857,14.2370909 9.685,13.9265455 C9.57214286,14.0181818 9.45928571,14.1112727 9.34642857,14.2036364 C9.11785714,14.3883636 8.89714286,14.5825455 8.67357143,14.7745455 C8.45,14.9665455 8.23571429,15.1687273 8.01642857,15.3658182 C7.79928571,15.5643636 7.58714286,15.7709091 7.37285714,15.9730909 L6.73714286,16.6007273 L6.13642857,17.2305455 C5.93571429,17.4516364 5.73071429,17.6698182 5.53428571,17.8909091 C5.14285714,18.3338182 4.75785714,18.7825455 4.39214286,19.2458182 C4.20857143,19.4763636 4.025,19.7083636 3.84928571,19.944 L3.58285714,20.2974545 L3.32428571,20.6552727 C2.98,21.1323636 2.65857143,21.6247273 2.34285714,22.1192727 C2.19,22.3694545 2.03428571,22.6181818 1.88714286,22.8698182 C1.74285714,23.1272727 1.59571429,23.3789091 1.46071429,23.6378182 C1.18142857,24.1490909 0.927857143,24.6741818 0.69,25.2014545 C0.473571429,25.7054545 0.272142857,26.2123636 0.0971428571,26.7287273 C0.385,27.0487273 0.685714286,27.3570909 0.992857143,27.6581818 C1.045,27.5149091 1.09428571,27.3701818 1.14928571,27.2261818 C1.34571429,26.7287273 1.575,26.2385455 1.81642857,25.7505455 L1.81642857,25.7505455 Z" id="Shape"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M2.61857143,28.7214545 C2.81428571,28.2232727 3.04357143,27.7330909 3.285,27.2458182 C3.77428571,26.272 4.34571429,25.3214545 4.96571429,24.3927273 C5.28,23.9316364 5.60285714,23.4727273 5.94357143,23.024 L6.19714286,22.6865455 L6.45785714,22.3541818 C6.63,22.1301818 6.81,21.912 6.99071429,21.6938182 C7.35142857,21.2581818 7.72214286,20.8298182 8.10071429,20.4065455 C8.28928571,20.1956364 8.48142857,19.9941818 8.67214286,19.7861818 L9.27428571,19.1614545 L9.87,18.5650909 C10.075,18.3694545 10.2778571,18.1709091 10.485,17.9774545 C10.9007143,17.5941818 11.32,17.2130909 11.7478571,16.8458182 C11.8821429,16.7309091 12.0171429,16.6167273 12.1528571,16.5032727 C11.8235714,15.8690909 11.49,15.2690909 11.3792857,15.3330909 C11.3185714,15.3694545 11.135,15.4843636 10.9185714,15.6145455 C10.8842857,15.6429091 10.85,15.6698182 10.815,15.6989091 C10.5857143,15.8829091 10.3657143,16.0778182 10.1414286,16.2698182 C9.91785714,16.4618182 9.70357143,16.664 9.48428571,16.8603636 C9.26642857,17.0596364 9.055,17.2661818 8.84071429,17.4683636 L8.205,18.0967273 L7.60428571,18.7265455 C7.40357143,18.9469091 7.19857143,19.1658182 7.00214286,19.3869091 C6.61071429,19.8298182 6.22571429,20.2785455 5.86,20.7410909 C5.67642857,20.9723636 5.49285714,21.2029091 5.31714286,21.4392727 L5.05142857,21.7927273 L4.79285714,22.1512727 C4.44928571,22.6283636 4.12642857,23.1207273 3.81142857,23.6145455 C3.65928571,23.8654545 3.50357143,24.1127273 3.35642857,24.3658182 C3.21214286,24.6210909 3.06428571,24.872 2.93,25.1309091 C2.65071429,25.6421818 2.39785714,26.1672727 2.16,26.6945455 C1.94642857,27.1927273 1.74642857,27.6938182 1.57357143,28.2029091 C1.87928571,28.48 2.19428571,28.7447273 2.51714286,29.0014545 C2.55071429,28.9090909 2.58214286,28.8145455 2.61857143,28.7214545 L2.61857143,28.7214545 Z" id="Shape"/>
<animateTransform
   attributeName="transform"
   id="plane"
   type="translate"
   from="15 40"
   to="45 8"
   dur="2s"
   begin="0s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    from="1 1"
    to="3 1.25"
    begin="0s"
    dur="2s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
</g>
```

**Option 2**

Obviously, if you do not want the scale to be animated, option 1 is probably not the best option. Instead, you could just want to use a parent `<g>` element that will encapsulate everything. The animateTransform will only override the transform of the inner `<g>` element, but you still have control over the outer `<g>` element:

```
<g transform="scale(3, 1.25)">
    <g id="plane" fill="#C3922E">
    <path d="M23.9521429,16.0247273 C24.0607143,15.4996364 22.1314286,9.57454545 22.1728571,9.41454545 C22.4507143,9.21454545 23.6271429,8.10618182 23.6271429,7.93745455 C23.6271429,7.76872727 22.8571429,6.99054545 22.72,7.01090909 C22.5835714,7.032 21.9328571,7.73818182 21.7728571,7.95127273 C21.63,7.95490909 21.26,5.92654545 21.4085714,5.77527273 C21.5578571,5.62327273 23.1907143,4.09963636 24.2078571,3.04290909 C25.0607143,2.15636364 25.2457143,0.761454545 25.1285714,0.641454545 C25.0107143,0.522181818 23.6407143,0.710545455 22.77,1.57890909 C21.7321429,2.61454545 20.2357143,4.27636364 20.0864286,4.42909091 C19.9378571,4.57963636 17.9464286,4.20290909 17.9492857,4.05745455 C18.1592857,3.89381818 18.8528571,3.23272727 18.8721429,3.09309091 C18.8928571,2.95490909 18.1285714,2.16872727 17.9628571,2.16872727 C17.7964286,2.16872727 16.7092857,3.36654545 16.5114286,3.64945455 C16.3542857,3.69236364 10.535,1.728 10.02,1.83927273 C9.505,1.94909091 8.88857143,2.42836364 9.02785714,2.57018182 C9.16714286,2.71127273 13.6592857,4.76872727 14.44,5.27054545 C15.22,5.77309091 16.7171429,7.23927273 16.7171429,7.41672727 C16.7171429,7.59490909 12.7042857,12.1796364 12.4707143,12.3730909 C12.2371429,12.5658182 10.5071429,11.7127273 9.83571429,11.808 C9.16357143,11.9025455 8.64428571,12.408 8.68642857,12.5665455 C8.72857143,12.7243636 11.3271429,13.9047273 11.1978571,14.1330909 C11.0971429,14.3098182 10.3671429,15.5018182 10.4507143,15.5869091 C10.5342857,15.6712727 11.7057143,14.9287273 11.8792857,14.8261818 C12.1042857,14.6930909 13.2635714,17.3410909 13.4178571,17.384 C13.5728571,17.4261818 14.07,16.8967273 14.1621429,16.2130909 C14.2557143,15.5287273 13.4178571,13.768 13.6078571,13.5301818 C13.7971429,13.2923636 18.3,9.20654545 18.4757143,9.20654545 C18.6507143,9.20654545 20.09,10.7301818 20.5828571,11.5250909 C21.0764286,12.3192727 23.0964286,16.8930909 23.2357143,17.0349091 C23.3735714,17.1774545 23.8428571,16.5483636 23.9521429,16.0247273 L23.9521429,20.0247273 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M1.81642857,25.7505455 C2.30571429,24.7767273 2.87714286,23.8269091 3.49642857,22.8974545 C3.81142857,22.4363636 4.13428571,21.9774545 4.47428571,21.5294545 L4.72714286,21.192 L4.98785714,20.8589091 C5.16071429,20.6356364 5.34071429,20.4181818 5.52071429,20.1992727 C5.88142857,19.7636364 6.25214286,19.3352727 6.63071429,18.912 C6.82,18.7010909 7.01214286,18.4989091 7.20214286,18.2909091 L7.80357143,17.6661818 L8.4,17.0705455 C8.60571429,16.8749091 8.80785714,16.6756364 9.015,16.4829091 C9.43071429,16.0989091 9.85,15.7185455 10.2785714,15.3512727 C10.2814286,15.3483636 10.2835714,15.3469091 10.2871429,15.3447273 C10.4628571,15.032 10.65,14.7229091 10.6971429,14.64 C10.7557143,14.5352727 10.2542857,14.2370909 9.685,13.9265455 C9.57214286,14.0181818 9.45928571,14.1112727 9.34642857,14.2036364 C9.11785714,14.3883636 8.89714286,14.5825455 8.67357143,14.7745455 C8.45,14.9665455 8.23571429,15.1687273 8.01642857,15.3658182 C7.79928571,15.5643636 7.58714286,15.7709091 7.37285714,15.9730909 L6.73714286,16.6007273 L6.13642857,17.2305455 C5.93571429,17.4516364 5.73071429,17.6698182 5.53428571,17.8909091 C5.14285714,18.3338182 4.75785714,18.7825455 4.39214286,19.2458182 C4.20857143,19.4763636 4.025,19.7083636 3.84928571,19.944 L3.58285714,20.2974545 L3.32428571,20.6552727 C2.98,21.1323636 2.65857143,21.6247273 2.34285714,22.1192727 C2.19,22.3694545 2.03428571,22.6181818 1.88714286,22.8698182 C1.74285714,23.1272727 1.59571429,23.3789091 1.46071429,23.6378182 C1.18142857,24.1490909 0.927857143,24.6741818 0.69,25.2014545 C0.473571429,25.7054545 0.272142857,26.2123636 0.0971428571,26.7287273 C0.385,27.0487273 0.685714286,27.3570909 0.992857143,27.6581818 C1.045,27.5149091 1.09428571,27.3701818 1.14928571,27.2261818 C1.34571429,26.7287273 1.575,26.2385455 1.81642857,25.7505455 L1.81642857,25.7505455 Z" id="Shape"/>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M2.61857143,28.7214545 C2.81428571,28.2232727 3.04357143,27.7330909 3.285,27.2458182 C3.77428571,26.272 4.34571429,25.3214545 4.96571429,24.3927273 C5.28,23.9316364 5.60285714,23.4727273 5.94357143,23.024 L6.19714286,22.6865455 L6.45785714,22.3541818 C6.63,22.1301818 6.81,21.912 6.99071429,21.6938182 C7.35142857,21.2581818 7.72214286,20.8298182 8.10071429,20.4065455 C8.28928571,20.1956364 8.48142857,19.9941818 8.67214286,19.7861818 L9.27428571,19.1614545 L9.87,18.5650909 C10.075,18.3694545 10.2778571,18.1709091 10.485,17.9774545 C10.9007143,17.5941818 11.32,17.2130909 11.7478571,16.8458182 C11.8821429,16.7309091 12.0171429,16.6167273 12.1528571,16.5032727 C11.8235714,15.8690909 11.49,15.2690909 11.3792857,15.3330909 C11.3185714,15.3694545 11.135,15.4843636 10.9185714,15.6145455 C10.8842857,15.6429091 10.85,15.6698182 10.815,15.6989091 C10.5857143,15.8829091 10.3657143,16.0778182 10.1414286,16.2698182 C9.91785714,16.4618182 9.70357143,16.664 9.48428571,16.8603636 C9.26642857,17.0596364 9.055,17.2661818 8.84071429,17.4683636 L8.205,18.0967273 L7.60428571,18.7265455 C7.40357143,18.9469091 7.19857143,19.1658182 7.00214286,19.3869091 C6.61071429,19.8298182 6.22571429,20.2785455 5.86,20.7410909 C5.67642857,20.9723636 5.49285714,21.2029091 5.31714286,21.4392727 L5.05142857,21.7927273 L4.79285714,22.1512727 C4.44928571,22.6283636 4.12642857,23.1207273 3.81142857,23.6145455 C3.65928571,23.8654545 3.50357143,24.1127273 3.35642857,24.3658182 C3.21214286,24.6210909 3.06428571,24.872 2.93,25.1309091 C2.65071429,25.6421818 2.39785714,26.1672727 2.16,26.6945455 C1.94642857,27.1927273 1.74642857,27.6938182 1.57357143,28.2029091 C1.87928571,28.48 2.19428571,28.7447273 2.51714286,29.0014545 C2.55071429,28.9090909 2.58214286,28.8145455 2.61857143,28.7214545 L2.61857143,28.7214545 Z" id="Shape"/>
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       id="plane"
       type="translate"
       from="15 40"
       to="45 8"
       dur="2s"
       begin="0s"
       fill="freeze"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
    />

  </g>
</g>
```

**Option 3**

Thanks to Robert Longson for this one. I was not aware of `additive="sum"`. `additive="sum"` allows you to merge multiple transforms rather than overriding them. Therefore, as an alternative to option 2, you can just do the following:

```
    <g id="plane" transform="scale(3, 1.25)" fill="#C3922E">
    <path d="M23.9521429,16.0247273 C24.0607143,15.4996364 22.1314286,9.57454545 22.1728571,9.41454545 C22.4507143,9.21454545 23.6271429,8.10618182 23.6271429,7.93745455 C23.6271429,7.76872727 22.8571429,6.99054545 22.72,7.01090909 C22.5835714,7.032 21.9328571,7.73818182 21.7728571,7.95127273 C21.63,7.95490909 21.26,5.92654545 21.4085714,5.77527273 C21.5578571,5.62327273 23.1907143,4.09963636 24.2078571,3.04290909 C25.0607143,2.15636364 25.2457143,0.761454545 25.1285714,0.641454545 C25.0107143,0.522181818 23.6407143,0.710545455 22.77,1.57890909 C21.7321429,2.61454545 20.2357143,4.27636364 20.0864286,4.42909091 C19.9378571,4.57963636 17.9464286,4.20290909 17.9492857,4.05745455 C18.1592857,3.89381818 18.8528571,3.23272727 18.8721429,3.09309091 C18.8928571,2.95490909 18.1285714,2.16872727 17.9628571,2.16872727 C17.7964286,2.16872727 16.7092857,3.36654545 16.5114286,3.64945455 C16.3542857,3.69236364 10.535,1.728 10.02,1.83927273 C9.505,1.94909091 8.88857143,2.42836364 9.02785714,2.57018182 C9.16714286,2.71127273 13.6592857,4.76872727 14.44,5.27054545 C15.22,5.77309091 16.7171429,7.23927273 16.7171429,7.41672727 C16.7171429,7.59490909 12.7042857,12.1796364 12.4707143,12.3730909 C12.2371429,12.5658182 10.5071429,11.7127273 9.83571429,11.808 C9.16357143,11.9025455 8.64428571,12.408 8.68642857,12.5665455 C8.72857143,12.7243636 11.3271429,13.9047273 11.1978571,14.1330909 C11.0971429,14.3098182 10.3671429,15.5018182 10.4507143,15.5869091 C10.5342857,15.6712727 11.7057143,14.9287273 11.8792857,14.8261818 C12.1042857,14.6930909 13.2635714,17.3410909 13.4178571,17.384 C13.5728571,17.4261818 14.07,16.8967273 14.1621429,16.2130909 C14.2557143,15.5287273 13.4178571,13.768 13.6078571,13.5301818 C13.7971429,13.2923636 18.3,9.20654545 18.4757143,9.20654545 C18.6507143,9.20654545 20.09,10.7301818 20.5828571,11.5250909 C21.0764286,12.3192727 23.0964286,16.8930909 23.2357143,17.0349091 C23.3735714,17.1774545 23.8428571,16.5483636 23.9521429,16.0247273 L23.9521429,20.0247273 Z" id="Shape"></path>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M1.81642857,25.7505455 C2.30571429,24.7767273 2.87714286,23.8269091 3.49642857,22.8974545 C3.81142857,22.4363636 4.13428571,21.9774545 4.47428571,21.5294545 L4.72714286,21.192 L4.98785714,20.8589091 C5.16071429,20.6356364 5.34071429,20.4181818 5.52071429,20.1992727 C5.88142857,19.7636364 6.25214286,19.3352727 6.63071429,18.912 C6.82,18.7010909 7.01214286,18.4989091 7.20214286,18.2909091 L7.80357143,17.6661818 L8.4,17.0705455 C8.60571429,16.8749091 8.80785714,16.6756364 9.015,16.4829091 C9.43071429,16.0989091 9.85,15.7185455 10.2785714,15.3512727 C10.2814286,15.3483636 10.2835714,15.3469091 10.2871429,15.3447273 C10.4628571,15.032 10.65,14.7229091 10.6971429,14.64 C10.7557143,14.5352727 10.2542857,14.2370909 9.685,13.9265455 C9.57214286,14.0181818 9.45928571,14.1112727 9.34642857,14.2036364 C9.11785714,14.3883636 8.89714286,14.5825455 8.67357143,14.7745455 C8.45,14.9665455 8.23571429,15.1687273 8.01642857,15.3658182 C7.79928571,15.5643636 7.58714286,15.7709091 7.37285714,15.9730909 L6.73714286,16.6007273 L6.13642857,17.2305455 C5.93571429,17.4516364 5.73071429,17.6698182 5.53428571,17.8909091 C5.14285714,18.3338182 4.75785714,18.7825455 4.39214286,19.2458182 C4.20857143,19.4763636 4.025,19.7083636 3.84928571,19.944 L3.58285714,20.2974545 L3.32428571,20.6552727 C2.98,21.1323636 2.65857143,21.6247273 2.34285714,22.1192727 C2.19,22.3694545 2.03428571,22.6181818 1.88714286,22.8698182 C1.74285714,23.1272727 1.59571429,23.3789091 1.46071429,23.6378182 C1.18142857,24.1490909 0.927857143,24.6741818 0.69,25.2014545 C0.473571429,25.7054545 0.272142857,26.2123636 0.0971428571,26.7287273 C0.385,27.0487273 0.685714286,27.3570909 0.992857143,27.6581818 C1.045,27.5149091 1.09428571,27.3701818 1.14928571,27.2261818 C1.34571429,26.7287273 1.575,26.2385455 1.81642857,25.7505455 L1.81642857,25.7505455 Z" id="Shape"/>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M2.61857143,28.7214545 C2.81428571,28.2232727 3.04357143,27.7330909 3.285,27.2458182 C3.77428571,26.272 4.34571429,25.3214545 4.96571429,24.3927273 C5.28,23.9316364 5.60285714,23.4727273 5.94357143,23.024 L6.19714286,22.6865455 L6.45785714,22.3541818 C6.63,22.1301818 6.81,21.912 6.99071429,21.6938182 C7.35142857,21.2581818 7.72214286,20.8298182 8.10071429,20.4065455 C8.28928571,20.1956364 8.48142857,19.9941818 8.67214286,19.7861818 L9.27428571,19.1614545 L9.87,18.5650909 C10.075,18.3694545 10.2778571,18.1709091 10.485,17.9774545 C10.9007143,17.5941818 11.32,17.2130909 11.7478571,16.8458182 C11.8821429,16.7309091 12.0171429,16.6167273 12.1528571,16.5032727 C11.8235714,15.8690909 11.49,15.2690909 11.3792857,15.3330909 C11.3185714,15.3694545 11.135,15.4843636 10.9185714,15.6145455 C10.8842857,15.6429091 10.85,15.6698182 10.815,15.6989091 C10.5857143,15.8829091 10.3657143,16.0778182 10.1414286,16.2698182 C9.91785714,16.4618182 9.70357143,16.664 9.48428571,16.8603636 C9.26642857,17.0596364 9.055,17.2661818 8.84071429,17.4683636 L8.205,18.0967273 L7.60428571,18.7265455 C7.40357143,18.9469091 7.19857143,19.1658182 7.00214286,19.3869091 C6.61071429,19.8298182 6.22571429,20.2785455 5.86,20.7410909 C5.67642857,20.9723636 5.49285714,21.2029091 5.31714286,21.4392727 L5.05142857,21.7927273 L4.79285714,22.1512727 C4.44928571,22.6283636 4.12642857,23.1207273 3.81142857,23.6145455 C3.65928571,23.8654545 3.50357143,24.1127273 3.35642857,24.3658182 C3.21214286,24.6210909 3.06428571,24.872 2.93,25.1309091 C2.65071429,25.6421818 2.39785714,26.1672727 2.16,26.6945455 C1.94642857,27.1927273 1.74642857,27.6938182 1.57357143,28.2029091 C1.87928571,28.48 2.19428571,28.7447273 2.51714286,29.0014545 C2.55071429,28.9090909 2.58214286,28.8145455 2.61857143,28.7214545 L2.61857143,28.7214545 Z" id="Shape"/>
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       id="plane"
       type="translate"
       from="15 40"
       to="45 8"
       dur="2s"
       begin="0s"
       fill="freeze"
       repeatCount="indefinite"
       additive="sum"
    />

  </g>
```

PS. My examples obviously do not look perfect, I left them for you to fix as you know exactly what you want. :)

Comment: Or use additive="sum" so the animation doesn't override.

Comment: Thank you @RobertLongson, I was not aware of that. I updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help and sharing valuable information. I appreciate your help. Path is scaring to me. It has lots of values. I feel difficult to figure it out.